# Getting started with a tree view/forum in PHP

Tags: php, treeview, forum

I am developing a tree view forum with PHP, MVC, and AJAX.  My database has two tables, as follows:

**thread**

- id_thread
- name
- creator
- date
- description
- parent_id

**answer**

- id_answer
- answer
- message
- user
- date

I am trying to develop a forum with *n* threads, that I would like to visually present in a tree view.  I am confused on how to get started with creating this tree view.

My approach is in the first level of threads is just autoincrement, then when the user click a thread, the parent_id of the next thread is the parent_id of the fist level, and so on.  Is there a better way to structure my data?

Any advice would be helpful, as I am a beginner trying to get started.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: post your code, we can't develop for you

Comment: Firstly, you don't really have a question to answer here, so try cleaning up your post to create a question or set of questions. Secondly, based on what you've posted above, you don't have anything that relates answers to threads. Right now you can have nested `thread`s but no messages within them.

Comment: I just need the idea, how will be your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the best way to display this client-side this is with the [YUI TreeView](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/).

Basically, you can pass it data in a variety of different formats (JSON is usually used) and it will generate this interactive tree in a div for you.

[image: YUI TreeView Example]

You can then add listeners for specific events, such as clicks and what not.

Here is an example:  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/treeview/default_tree.html

Comment: I just need an idea in how to make a forum with n leves(threads) without frameworks, but taking control of parent_id for making a tree view with my database, thanks for answers

Comment: @GeorgeBecj, your question doesn't make any sense.  I've tried to help you, but if this isn't the answer, then I have absolutely no idea what you are asking.

Comment: no I think its a good answers, I will try to figure out better how can I do that and then I will post my code with a concrete question, sorry